# Sorting each object's key in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have the following array of object :

```
var wordSpecsArr = [{a: 2, b: 2},{a: 1, b: 1, c: 1, d: 1},{b: 2, a: 2},{d: 2, a: 2},{a: 2, b: 2}]
```

and I would like to sort each object by keys so that it will become:

```
var wordSpecsArr = [{a: 2, b: 2},{a: 1, b: 1, c: 1, d: 1},{a: 2, b: 2},{a: 2, d: 2},{a: 2, b: 2}]
```

I have tried the following code:

```
//sort keys
wordSpecsArr.forEach((obj) => {
    var ordered = {};
    Object.keys(obj).sort().forEach((key) => {
        ordered[key] = obj[key]
    });
});
```

But it did not work. I would really appreciate any help

Comment: As far as I know, you can never be sure of the keys order in an object.

Comment: @ObsidianAge It's a different case.

Comment: replace `forEach` with `map` and add `return ordered` in the callback - that should solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this.**

```js
var wordSpecsArr = [{a: 2, b: 2},{a: 1, b: 1, c: 1, d: 1},{b: 2, a: 2},{d: 2, a: 2},{a: 2, b: 2}]


var wordSpecsArr = [{a: 2, b: 2},{a: 1, b: 1, c: 1, d: 1},{a: 2, b: 2},{a: 2, d: 2},{a: 2, b: 2}]

//sort keys
let op =[];
wordSpecsArr.forEach((obj) => {
    let ordered = {};
    Object.keys(obj).sort().forEach((key) => {
        ordered[key] = obj[key]
    });
   op.push(ordered)
});

console.log(op)
```